# Trying to execute code on device ready

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am trying to execute some Javascript code on deviceready by using a listener.

It doesn't seem to be calling the code - I'm getting nothing in my console, and none of the variables are set.

This is the code example I'm using:

```
    <script>

                // Cordova is ready
function onDeviceReady() {
  var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "my.db"});

  db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_table');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_table (id integer primary key, data text, data_num integer)');

    tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO test_table (data, data_num) VALUES (?,?)", ["test", 100], function(tx, res) {
      console.log("insertId: " + res.insertId + " -- probably 1");
      console.log("rowsAffected: " + res.rowsAffected + " -- should be 1");

      tx.executeSql("select count(id) as cnt from test_table;", [], function(tx, res) {
        console.log("res.rows.length: " + res.rows.length + " -- should be 1");
        console.log("res.rows.item(0).cnt: " + res.rows.item(0).cnt + " -- should be 1");
      });

    }, function(e) {
      console.log("ERROR: " + e.message);
    });
  });
}
// Wait for Cordova to load
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

</script>
```

Now, I'm not primarily a Javascript developer (so this question may be simple), but is there some reason why the code is not executing? Do I have to run it in an anonymous function?

How do I get the onDeviceReady() function to execute?

Comment: Just to check... you are running this in a Cordova environment (only asking since the Cordova tag wasn't included in your question)?

Comment: Ultimately it will be, yes, but right now it's being run just as a mobile site during testing.

Comment: Oh you're right. When I loaded it up in Ripple and ran it, it launches it. Thanks! Put that down as the answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Done. I'm not too familiar with Cordova, so feel free to edit [my (CW) answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) if you can add anything.

Comment: I'm honestly just starting with it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`deviceready` is a special Cordova event; unless you launch your code in a Cordova environment, the event will never get fired (and your code will never get executed).

You **can** run Cordova in the browser by adding the browser as a platform. For more info, see http://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/09/24/Browser-as-a-platform-for-your-PhoneGapCordova-apps.

You could *also* use something like Ripple to emulate the Cordova environment in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Since Cordova-SQLitePlugin API is asynchronous, you should execute transaction after the db is available/created. Try to implement it in a similar way as below:

```
    var openDb = function (name, ok, error) {
      try {
        // SQLitePlugin always uses callbacks to specify the status of 'open' operation
        var dbRef = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: name},
          function (db) {
            log("DataBase " + name + " opened!");
            ok(db);
          }, function (e) {
            try {
              dbRef.close();
            } catch (e) {
              log("Could not close database", e);
            }
            error(e);
          });
      } catch (e) {
        log("Could not open " + name + " DataBase");
        error(e);
      }
    };

    openDb("my.db", function(db){
       db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_table');
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_table (id integer primary key, data text, data_num integer)');

        tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO test_table (data, data_num) VALUES (?,?)", ["test", 100], function(tx, res) {
          console.log("insertId: " + res.insertId + " -- probably 1");
          console.log("rowsAffected: " + res.rowsAffected + " -- should be 1");

          tx.executeSql("select count(id) as cnt from test_table;", [], function(tx, res) {
            console.log("res.rows.length: " + res.rows.length + " -- should be 1");
            console.log("res.rows.item(0).cnt: " + res.rows.item(0).cnt + " -- should be 1");
          });

        }, function(e) {
          console.log("ERROR: " + e.message);
        });
      });
    });
```